# Ctrl + N shortcut - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In the android document I found <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> will create a new file. But when I try the same in my android studio it's opening exiting files.

Android Studio version : 0.8.2

Following is what I found in android docs

> Creating new files
>
> You can quickly add new code and resource files by
> clicking the appropriate directory in the Project pane and pressing
> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, on Mac). Based on the type of directory selected,
> Android Studio offers to create the appropriate file type.
>
> For example, if you select a layout directory, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, and
> select Layout resource file, a dialog opens so you can name the file
> (you can exclude the .xml suffix) and choose a root view element. The
> editor then switches to the layout design editor so you can begin
> designing your layout.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I think we can safely assume that anything related to Android Studio **0.8.2** can be ignored as completely out of date.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That documentation and given short cut might be old, not sure though! but as per the [key reference](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) given, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> is used for navigating to the particular class.

[image]

For getting NEW files menu, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>.